# As a South Korean, would it be ok to stay after my Residence Permit expires?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a South Korean national, and currently hold a Aufenthaltstitle in Germany as a job seeker, which is expiring as of Dec. 24. I had previously worked in Germany for almost 3 years, then my employment ended on June 30 and I was able to extend my stay as a job seeker until Dec.24.

I have recently traveled to the US, and on my way back I got my passport stamped in Lisbon on Nov.15, and I am curious to know whether this allows me to stay in Germany longer (up to 90 days from Nov.15) than my Aufenthaltstitles' expiration date.

---

To add a bit...

My question is whether the entry stamp in Lisbon on Nov. 15 would still be valid, even if my residence is not expired at that point yet. Or do I need to exit the country and get another stamp after the Aufenthaltstitel is expired. Any clarification will be very much appreciated.

Comment: When did you leave Germany (or any countries in the Schengen)?

Comment: I left Germany for the US on October 29th and came back to Germany via Lisbon on Nov.15th.

Comment: You should ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange, but I *think* not. 90/180 and the like are for C visa, you have a D.